# Need to sort complex objects, like dominoe

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

Here is a situation. For example I have a structure like this (code is simplified):

```
class Dominoe 
{
    ctor Dominoe(left, right)        

    string LeftSide;
    string RightSide;
}
```

And I have data, somewhat like this:

```
Dominoe("2", "3"), Dominoe("1", "2"), Dominoe("4", "5"), Dominoe("3", "4")
```

I know that there won't be any gaps in dominoes, nor repeats.
I need to order this collection, so every RightSide would be connected to appropriate LeftSide. Like so:

```
Dominoe("1", "2"), Dominoe("2", "3"), Dominoe("3", "4"), Dominoe("4", "5")
```

Values - not numbers. Just need a clue.

Right now I've done this task in 2 steps. Primary - i'm looking for the entry point. The dominoe which have LeftSide not presented in any other Dominoe RightSide. After that i switch it with 0 index item. Secondly - i'm looking for next dominoe which have LeftSide same as RightSide of my entry dominoe and so on in cycle.

I'm doing this in C#, but this really doesn't matter.

The problem is - i don't think it's best algorithm. Any ideas will be great. Thx.

**EDITED !**

Was my bad to talk about numbers.

Let's change Dominoe for trevel cards.

So it'll be like:

```
TravelCard ("Dublin", "New York"), TravelCard ("Moscow", "Dublin"), TravelCard ("New York", "Habana")
```

Comment: do you really need SORT, or maybe find BEST FIT to particular situation?

Comment: If you have working code you might want to post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Code doesn't matter, really. Concept is more required. I'll update question in a minute.

Comment: Is your `rightside` really allways one more then `leftside`, or is `(4, 6)` also a possible combination?

Comment: Why are you storing the values as `string` instead of `int`?

Comment: @juharr he is only comparing values for equality, it does not really matter whether they are strings or int

Comment: This is not a sorting problem...

Comment: @HugoRune True, but still, storing numbers as strings is odd.  And now the OP explained it better.

Comment: I modified question.

Comment: This is really a graph problem.  You've got nodes  (the left and right values) and directed edges (the actual object that links a left and right value) and you want to find a path that will cover all the edges.

Comment: if you have a dictionary of dominoes with the left side as keys, and a dictionary with the right sides as keys, your current algorithm should be quite efficient, O(N), assuming each key occurs only once, so there is only one valid solution.

Comment: This problem is equivalent to a problem called Hamiltonian Path in a Directed Graph, and unfortunately it's NP-hard, meaning there's no known polynomial-time solution.  Also (unless there are other constraints on your input that you're not telling us), *there might be no solution*.

Comment: (To build an instance of HPiaDG from this problem, create a vertex for each domino, and for each pair of dominos u and v having rightSide(u) = leftSide(v), add an edge uv.)

Comment: @juharr Graphs - I don't really know much about this. :) Thx for advice.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have huge amount of your cards your solution will work. Otherwise you can consider 2 dictionaries to make searches constants and keep `O(N)` complexity:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Dominoe
    {
        public Dominoe(int left, int right)
        {
            LeftSide = left;
            RightSide = right;
        }

        public int LeftSide;
        public int RightSide;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = new List<Dominoe>()
            {
                new Dominoe(2, 3), 
                new Dominoe(1, 2), 
                new Dominoe(4, 5), 
                new Dominoe(3, 4)
            };

            var dicLeft = new Dictionary<int, Dominoe>();
            var dicRigth = new Dictionary<int, Dominoe>();

            foreach (var item in input)
            {
                dicLeft.Add(item.LeftSide, item);
                dicRigth.Add(item.RightSide, item);
            }

            Dominoe first = null;

            foreach(var item in input)
            {
                if (!dicRigth.ContainsKey(item.LeftSide))
                {
                    first = item;
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", first.LeftSide, first.RightSide));

            for(int i = 0; i < input.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                first = dicLeft[first.RightSide];
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", first.LeftSide, first.RightSide));
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for suggestion. The size could be any.

Comment: @Kindzoku: How big is `any`? A thousand? A million? More?