# C# create a route from pair objects

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have an issue.

I need to create a route from cards. A card contains a departure point and a destination point. For instance, there are three cards "**London -> New-York**", "**Sydney -> Moscow"** and "**New-York -> Sydney**". After sorting there must be a collection "**London -> New-York, New-York -> Sydney, Sydney -> Moscow**".

Could you help me, what algorithm should I use for solving this issue? I can do it by many loops but this way seems for me not optimal.

Comment: Sounds like the travelling salesman problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: Seems like a (worse) duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598168/need-to-sort-complex-objects-like-dominoe.

Comment: Do you know the starting point `London` and/or the end point `Moscow`? What if multiple routes are possible? How many cards are in the collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose to build 2 hash-maps (regular Dictionary of c#) to build back and forward [Adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). After this just iterate over list of nodes that have no input links (start nodes). You can optimize following algorithm (a) if you know what is start node (b) if you have only single start node.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using CityPair = System.Tuple<string, string>; //just for short
namespace cards
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var source = new[]
            {
                Tuple.Create("London", "New-York"),
                Tuple.Create("Sydney", "Moscow"),
                Tuple.Create("New-York", "Sydney")
            };

            //convert to hash-map 
            var graphIncedence = //not needed if you know start-node
              new Dictionary<string, CityPair>(source
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Item1, x=>x));
            //convert to inverted hash_map 
            var invertedGraph = 
                 new Dictionary<string, CityPair>(source
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Item2, x => x));
            //find all nodes without input links
            var startNodes = graphIncedence
                .Where((pair) => !graphIncedence.ContainsKey(pair.Value.Item2))
                .Select(pair=> pair.Value).ToList();
            //for each start node build a path
            foreach (var start in startNodes) //remove it if only 1 start node
            {
                Console.Write("Start node is: '{0}'", start.Item2);

                //produce list where items just follow after startNode
                for (var next = start.Item1; next != null;)
                {
                    Console.Write("-> {0}", next);
                    CityPair result;
                    next = !invertedGraph.TryGetValue(next, out result) 
                           ? null : result.Item1;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
 Start node is: 'Moscow'-> Sydney-> New-York-> London
```